# How does "/" really work on two row vectors?

Tags: matlab

I have the following basic observation:

```
[1 2 3 4]/[2 4 6 8] % output: 0.5
[1 2 3 4]/[2 3 4 5] % output: 0.7407
([1 2 3 4]*[2 4 6 8] % error of course)
```

It does not look for me as A*inv(B) kind of operation (nor like mrdivide on timeseries which would work like [1 2 3 4]./[2 4 6 8] if Im not mistaken).

Now, my question is, what operation does "/" define on two row vectors with the same length?

---

UPDATE:
@user1884905 gave the idea that a/b on two row vectors might minimise `norm(b*x - a)`. So far it seemed to work on some numeric tests. If it is true, can you give some official reference behind this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it seems I was right. From [MathWorks mrdivide](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mrdivide.html)

"If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a row vector with n elements or a matrix with n columns, then x = B/A returns a least-squares solution of the system of equations x*A = B."

Comment: Interesting... especially for symbolics  "Warning: System is inconsistent. Solution does not exist. " Of course Least Squares is not an option...